# Object die incompatible with int

Tags: java, object

Given a class Die and it contains a random value for a six sided die.

Another class PairOfDice needs to access getvalue in Die and store two die values.

An error:  incompatible types: Die cannot be converted to int occurs when PairOfDice is executed.
    return dieOneValue;

How can this problem be fixed? And are there any other suggestions for the java code? Thanks in advance for any advice!

```
public class Die {
public static Random rand = new Random();
private int sides; // Number of sides
private int value; // Die's value
public Die() {
    sides = 6;
    roll();
}
public void roll() {
    value = rand.nextInt(sides) + 1;
}
public int getSides() {
    return sides;
}
public int getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

The second class given is:

```
public class PairOfDice {
private Die dieOneValue;
private Die dieTwoValue;
public void PairOfDice() {
 Die die = new Die();
 dieOneValue.roll();
 dieTwoValue.roll();
}

public int getDieOneValue() {
  return dieOneValue;
}
public int getDieTwoValue() {
  return dieTwoValue;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you think `return dieOneValue;` should do (considering the method it's in has a return type of `int`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you define dieOneValue and dieTwoValue as type Die and then have the get methods return dieOneValue and dieTwoValue, but the methods have an int return type.  You need to either change the return type of getDieOneValue and getDieTwoValue to Die or call `dieOneValue.getValue()` and `dieTwoValue.getValue()` instead of just returning the Die instances.

It also doesn't look like you properly instantiate dieOneValue and dieTwoValue in the PairOfDice method. Shouldn't it be something more like this?

```
public void PairOfDice() {
 dieOneValue = new Die();
 dieTwoValue = new Die();
}
```